# How to modify specify localstorage item in vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage, vuex

I want to change specify `localstorage` item in vuex.

For example, I have `localstorage` item like this:

```
{
  'id' = 1, 'another' = 2
}
```

I want to change just `id`, how can I do this?

I just know the basic usage like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.currentUser))
```

I tried something like this but looks like its not working

```
localStorage.setItem("user.id", "2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getItem()` to get current value and [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to assign values as following:

```
const newValue = {
   ...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")),
   id: 2
}

localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(newValue))
```

Comment: ya, its work, but need refresh to take effect.
since im using use router-link, so im not refresh the page..

Comment: I think you don't need to refresh the page. I don't know about Vue.js but I think you need to invoke related functions/services to take effect after assigning the value.

Answer (score 1):

You can't exactly because localStorage stores everything as strings. Best is just to replace the entire object by `JSON.stringify`-ing the object again after modifying it.

So essentially:

```
// Get the user from localStorage and parse into object
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
// Update an attribute on the user object
user.id = 2;
// Update the user in localStorage and stringify to string
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
```

Comment: I think you need to null-check in case `user` item does not exist currently in order to avoid `id of null` error in line `user.id = 2`.

Comment: Good idea @HarunYilmaz 

Comment: @DelenaMalan u can fine my code here https://github.com/jazuly1/error/blob/master/1.js